# Como indicar numa regex que os símbolos '(' e ')', os parênteses, são uma das alternativas numa lista de símbolos em Java?

Tags: java, regex

Estou desenvolvendo um código que captura um texto usando expressões regulares (regex). Esse texto é constituído de parênteses.

A questão é que os parênteses são usados nas expressões regulares como definidor de grupos e eu quero utilizá-los como literais.

Já tentei usar `\\(` como escape, mas o IDE Eclipse já rejeita, dizendo que apenas alguns outros símbolos são escapados (os caracteres tradicionais de Java).

Tentei `\\\\(`, chega a rodar, mas logo dá erro, e ao conferir indica que na verdade ele "traduz" para `\\(` em vez de `(` como literal.

> "Em primeiro lugar, quem é 1º colocado, em segundo quem é segundo (que é Rubinho)"

```
([A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\"\'!?$%:;,º°ª]+)
```

Queria adicionar os parênteses nessa lista de caracteres.

Comment: é `\\(` mesmo, e ele tem que traduzir para `\(` sim, que é para o RegEx. escapar corretamente. Inclusive, estas aspas precisam de duas barras também. Uma para escapar para o Java, e por consequência sobrar uma para escapar a RegEx.

Comment: @Bacco quando ponho \\" ou \\' como sugerido indica-se erro assim como \(. Apenas com \" compila. Aí o que é \\" é na verdade \ seguido de aspas e dá erro. \( seria \ seguida de parêntese.

Comment: Indica erro na compilação, ou o editor de código reclama? Precisa ver se é um erro na sintaxe ou no editor. De qq forma, você precisa [edit] e por o trecho de código na pergunta, senão fica meio complicado de analisarmos o contexto todo pra ver se o problema é mesmo na barra só.

Comment: @Bacco você estava certo, mas estranhamente não estava aceitando a construção com \\(, rodava, mas indicava erro na regex, já com apenas um \( o editor indicava erro. Mas como confirmado por utluiz é apenas um escape quando é aspas. Obrigado.

Comment: Como ele disse, é um escape se for para escapar para o Java. Se a barra faz parte da RegEx, são sempre duas, se a barra não faz parte da regex (o que parece ser o seu caso, pelo que vc disse), é uma só. Não interessa se são aspas ou se são quaisquer outros caracteres. O importante é você entender em qual das duas camadas está fazendo o escape (e adaptar para seu contexto). Não vá acostumar com "quando é X use Y", senão pode se confundir. O importante é entender qual camada (Regex ou Java) está sendo escapada, e não qual caractere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O processo para "escapar" um caractere especial numa `String` no Java tem dois passos:

1. "Escapar" caracteres especiais para o Java.
2. "Escapar" caracteres especiais para a expressão regular, que pode incluir, "escapar" o caractere de "escape".

## Exemplo: escapando parêntesis

O parêntesis não é um caractere especial para o Java, mas é para a expressão regular, portanto, ele deve receber um caractere de escape `\` antes (Motivo #1).

Como o caractere `\` é especial no Java, ele deve ter um escape e se tornar `\\` (Motivo #2).

Resultado:

```
String regex1 = "\\(";
String regex2 = "\\)";
```

## Exemplo: escapando aspas

Aspas duplas são especiais para o Java, portanto precisam de um escape com `\` (Motivo #1), mas não são especiais para as expressões regulares.

Portanto, o resultado é:

```
String regex3 = "\"";
```

Aspas simples não são especiais na maioria das vezes (não me lembro no momento se aspas simples podem ter significado especial em alguma implementação de expressões regulares), portanto não precisam de escape pelo menos para os usos mais comuns.

```
String regex4 = "'";
```

## Juntando tudo

Para capturar um texto entre parêntesis, você precisa dos seguintes elementos:

1. Uma classe de caracteres para capturar tudo que pode estar entre os parêntesis. Neste caso:

   ```
   [A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ"'!?$%:;,º°ª ]
   ```
2. Um quantificador: `+`
3. Delimitadores para o grupo de caracteres a ser capturado (os delimitadores vêm antes dos caracteres limite se você não quer incluir os parêntesis do texto original no grupo capturado): `(` e `)`
4. Os caracteres limites para o grupo, ou os parêntesis neste caso: `\(` e `\)`

Convertendo cada um para strings Java, podemos construir a expressão final:

1. Classe com escape nas aspas duplas:

   ```
   "[A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\"'!?$%:;,º°ª ]"
   ```
2. Quantificador:

   ```
   "[A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\"'!?$%:;,º°ª ]+"
   ```
3. Delimitadores:

   ```
   "([A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\"'!?$%:;,º°ª ]+)"
   ```
4. Caracteres limite, com escape no escape:

   ```
   "\\(([A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\"'!?$%:;,º°ª ]+)\\)"
   ```

Código de exemplo:

```
String s = "Em primeiro lugar, quem é 1º colocado, em segundo quem é segundo (que é Rubinho)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(([A-Za-z0-9çãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\"'!?$%:;,º°ª ]+')\\)").matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Resultado:

> que é Rubinho

## Alternativa

Ao invés de tentar especificar *todos* caracteres que porventura podem estar dentro dos parêntesis, que tal apenas eliminar os que não podem?

Por exemplo, a classe `[^()]` nega os parêntesis e captura tudo menos eles.

Aplicando todos os passos do tópico anterior, mudando apenas a classe do item #1, podemos chegar ao seguinte exemplo, que tem o mesmo resultado:

```
String s = "Em primeiro lugar, quem é 1º colocado, em segundo quem é segundo (que é Rubinho)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]+)\\)").matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: +1. Eu tava mandando um exemplo no IDEONE só pra resolver de imediato, mas nada melhor do que uma resposta completa ;)

Comment: Obrigado, foi uma resposta bastante completa. Me ajudou e muito, @utluiz