# Como usar expressões regulares?

Tags: c#, regex, expressões

Eu tenho uma string com esse valor:

> Romania","PROXY_IP":"93.118.243.19","PROXY_LAST_UPDATE
>   Indonesia","PROXY_IP":"117.102.88.121","PROXY_LAST_UPDATE
>   Russia","PROXY_IP":"194.135.97.178","PROXY_LAST_UPDATE
>   Malaysia,"PROXY_IP":"192.228.193.78","PROXY_LAST_UPDATE

e encontrar todos partes com " "PROXY_IP":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" "
Código que tentei:

```
static Regex ipR = new Regex(@""PROXY_IP":"\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}"");
```

porém ficou tudo vermelho... Não sei como fazer para o Regex buscar por aspas no meio da string também

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172741/como-indicar-numa-regex-que-os-s%C3%ADmbolos-e-os-par%C3%AAnteses-s%C3%A3o-uma-das-al  no exemplo de escapando aspas, creio que vai te ajudar bastante

Comment: @LuizAugusto obrigado pela resposta, mas não ajudou muito visto que expressões em java é diferente do que em c#

Comment: Não programo muito em C# mas acredito que o problema [esteja nas aspas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3458097) mesmo. Quanto ao IP, acho que dá para "simplificar" para `\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}` - não esqueça de escapar o ponto também, pois `.` significa "qualquer caractere", enquanto `\.` significa "ponto". Claro que vc pode complicar ainda mais, caso queira uma [regex que só aceite números entre zero e 255](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)

Comment: Outro link, http://aurelio.net/regex/c/ é bem completo o material do Aurelio.

Comment: Não sei como define a melhor resposta, mas muito obrigado @hkotsubo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para usar aspas em uma Regex, você precisa usar a contra-barra (\).
Ou seja, seu regex ficaria assim:

```
(\"PROXY_IP\":\"\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\")
```

Existe alguns sites muito bons ensinando regex e que são interativos. Dê uma olhada no [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3v14p), criei um exemplo usando seu caso.

Comment: Sim, estudei um pouco e entendi a "lógica do regex" haha
Obrigado! Já foi resolvida a duvida